# Cant cast float8 to Single? System.InvalidCastException in Npgsql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, npgsql

I am using Entity Framework 6 with Npgsql. Just updated from Npgql.EntityFramework to version 3.1.1 of the EntityFramework6.Npgsql package.

After some small issues resulting from the move that were easily fixed I am now stuck on this exception. From the logs I get:

```
Date = 2016-08-17 15:10:58 | Severity = Exception | Source = Reflect.Logging.SimpleLog.SimpleLogLogger.LogError | ThreadId = 7 | Type = System.InvalidCastException | Source = 
    Npgsql.SimpleTypeHandler`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].ReadFully | Message = Can't cast database type float8 to Single | StackTrace =    at Npgsql.SimpleTypeHandler`1[T].ReadFully[T2] (Npgsql.ReadBuffer buf, Int32 len, Npgsql.BackendMessages.FieldDescription fieldDescription) in <filename unknown>:line 0
           at Npgsql.TypeHandler.ReadFully[T] (Npgsql.BackendMessages.DataRowMessage row, Int32 len, Npgsql.BackendMessages.FieldDescription fieldDescription) in <filename unknown>:line 0
           at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.ReadColumnWithoutCache[T] (Int32 ordinal) in <filename unknown>:line 0
```

Looking at my Postgres schema, I see no fields of type 'float8'.

This is the methods that throws the exception:

```
public List<TUser> GetByEmail(string email)
{
    return Context.Set<TUser>().Where(q => q.Email == email).ToList();
}
```

And this is the db schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "Users" (
    "Id" integer NOT NULL,
    "UtcOffset" double precision,
    "Guid" uuid,
    "NotificationHourOfDay" integer,
    "NotificationTimeOfDay" time without time zone,
    "SendNotifications" boolean,
    "IsLocked" boolean,
    "Username" character varying,
    "Screenname" character varying,
    "Email" character varying,
    "IsConfirmed" boolean,
    "ConfirmationToken" character varying,
    "LastActivityDateUtc" timestamp without time zone,
    "SignUpDateUtc" timestamp without time zone,
    "SignUpIpAddress" character varying,
    "CountryCode" character varying,
    "CountryName" character varying,
    "PasswordResetToken" uuid,
    "PasswordResetRequestDateUtc" timestamp without time zone,
    "IsAwaitingPasswordResetTokenConfirmation" boolean,
    "MessageHistory" jsonb,
    "SendDigest" boolean,
    "DigestLastSendDateUtc" timestamp without time zone,
    "SignUpUserAgent" text,
    "SignUpApplication" character varying,
    "PaymentProviderCustomerId" character varying,
    "Discriminator" character varying,
    "UserName" character varying,
    "PasswordHash" bytea,
    "Salt" bytea,
    "Profile" jsonb,
    "LegacyId" integer
);
```

Can someone shine some light on the origin of this exception and what I might be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the fields in the database to the question as well as the code that's causing the exception? Otherwise, it's a mystery.

Comment: I edited my questions to include the information

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this is a mismatch between a field in your database and the in-memory class that will be mapped to the table entry. Npgsql uses float8 to represent doubles. My guess is that your in-memory class has the UtcOffset as a float and should be a double.